# Programming a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, spi, uart, fifo

I'm quite new in this, so I was hoping if someone could put me on a right track for programming *PIC24FJ128GA202*

In my new work position I was handed a task to program the mentioned mcu as a learning excercise, but I don't know where to begin.

I was told, that first thing I should do is to initialize the adequate pins and write a FIFO buffer for the UART module.

In the end, I should be able to send commands to mcu from computer via usb/uart adapter and have the mcu send analog signals to hardware.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: What exactly do you have in front of you and did you read the controller's datasheet and user manual?

Comment: I would add that for a novice on microcontrollers, the datasheets can be quite intimidating. In that case, try to find tutorials on the subject to make yourself familiar with the matter.

Comment: One good habit at the start of each MCU project is to download and read all silicon errata for the MCU. There's _always_ some known hardware errors, and if you spend 15 minutes reading through the errata at the start of the project, you might save days/weeks of troubleshooting later, in case you happen to stumble upon a hardware bug.

Comment: I don't feel like the OP has done his homework before asking the question

Comment: Microchip documentaiton is generally lacking so on top of the datasheet being intimidating the first time, this particular product family has other hurdles.  Good thing is there are tens to hundreds of thousands of open source examples out there that will get you through this problem.  Unfortunately you probably dont have 30 years to finish this task so you cant read all of them, you can pick a few and go with those, comparing the code to the documentation, then modifying the example or making your own from scratch.

Comment: 90+% of baremetal programming is reading, reading the documentation on all the parts, reading examples if you can find them, reading through the chip vendors libraries if they provide sources.  Then there is a chunk of time spent hacking for lack of a better term as all of the documentation is buggy, dont trust it, test it.  Then finally between documentation and experiments against that documentation you can spend a few percent of the overall project time actually writing the program.

Comment: @old_timer This is different from any other sort of programming how exactly?

Comment: @DanMills are writing software to talk directly or through a library directly to hardware to manipulate the peripherals.  A spi controller to talk to a temperature sensor, humidity, etc.  accelerometer and a gps and compass.  motor controllers, etc.  granted you can find libraries to make it app like but not uncommon to have to port them or write your own, knowledge of the busses, protocol, etc.  every one of these items inside and out has a datasheet, a scope, blinking led, and uart are your primary debug tools.  not something you use when developing a web page or phone app..

Comment: @old_timer I have done plenty of small core embedded in assembler (about half a dozen or so), C, Forth and other weirder things. My point was that ALL library documentations sucks, all hardware abstraction layers are buggy (Be they bare metal HAL(ST Looking at YOU!), BSP, VxWorks, Linux or Windows) and often the only way to figure them out is with experimental hacks. The real difference is that once you get to big machines, slapping a scope or LA on the I2C bus and triggering it on a GPO ceases to be a really useful approach, and the big boxes are too annoying to test with bare metal code.

Comment: @DanMills PIC24FJ128GA202 is not a big machine, it is in the use a scope or blink an led category.  generally agree with your statements, with an occasional exception.  Was trying to say the reading of datasheets, schematics, libraries, etc are most of the work.  Then hacking at stuff is next, then writing the actual program is a small percentage of the overall time.  Unlike an app on an OS where you learn the C library calls you prefer to use and not need to look at the man page for the next 40 years...

Comment: The vendor provided libraries are often scary, yet as a professional IMO you should take responsibility for the ones you use, your boss wont care that the project failed because of some library you downloaded and linked in had issues, thats still on you.  If they dont look scary to you, you need to keep looking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an appropriate programmer for your microcontroller (in your case a PIC Programmer), assuming that this is not the first time your company is working with this controller, there should be one around.

Once you have all the required hardware, you need to set up the Integrated Development Environment (IDE). For PIC Processors this is MP Lab and can be downloaded on the Microchip Website.

When starting a new design, it's always best to start from an existing project you know it works, to verify the whole programming process works as expected. So either you have a former project of your company or you take one of the examples provided by the manufacturer. Once you verified your setup and programming works as expected, you can start to modify the existing code according to your needs.

PIC controllers are widely used, so there are tons of tutorials and examples about this microcontroller out there (e.g. https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/writing-your-first-pic-microcontroller-program)